# Bootloader STm32

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I trying to flash using the internal bootloader(system memory) of stm32L073Rz nucleo board. I have read the documents AN2606, AN3155 and set the BOOT0 pin=1.By default USART2 on nucleo board is accessible by stlink interface and the same USART2 is used by the bootloader to listen for data, I using GTK term in ubuntu to connect via /dev/ttyAMC0(USART2) but unable to receive an ACK from the device, as mentioned in AN3155 I am sending 0X7F to the device. is this procedure works or are there any better alternatives to communicate with the bootloader?

Comment: Why aren't you programming the target via the integrated ST-Link/V2-1?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to load your program via the target MCU's internal bootloader via UART2.  Is that right?  To do that you may have to disconnect the board's default connection between the target's UART2 and the integrated ST-Link MCU (i.e., you'll be bypassing the ST-Link MCU).  See the UART Communication section in the board's User Manual ([UM1724](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf)) and this excerpt.

> The USART2 interface available on PA2 and PA3 of the STM32
>   microcontroller can be connected to ST-LINK MCU, ST morpho connector
>   or to Arduino connector. The choice can be changed by setting the
>   related solder bridges. By default the USART2 communication between
>   the target STM32 and ST-LINK MCU is enabled, in order to support
>   virtual COM port for Mbed™ (SB13 and SB14 ON, SB62 and SB63 OFF). **If
>   the communication between the target STM32 PA2 (D1) or PA3 (D0) and
>   shield or extension board is required, SB62 and SB63 should be ON,
>   SB13 and SB14 should be OFF**.

However, typically one would simply program the target MCU using the integrated ST-Link/V2-1.  This is how the board is configured by default.  In other words, it's not necessary to use the internal bootloader because this board has an intergrated ST-Link, which is easier to use.

Comment: @ kkrambo Okay thank you for your information. I'm trying to learn to flash using the bootloaders. Are there any resources available for developing custom bootloaders on stm32 and is the source code for stm32 bootloader is open?